# Gradle task assembleDebug failed in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I encountered this issue trying to run flutter. This happened when I cloned a project from GitHub and then I tried to run its dependency, which didn't run. So what I did was start the project again and typed in the same code base.  I saw then this came up:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download flutter_embedding_debug.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408)
      > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar'.
            > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: do you have intenet connection on your machine?

Comment: yes i have an internet connection